# php codeigniter cannot access file pdf in hosting

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf

I can access my file and work correctly in localhost, but problem starts when I move it to the host.

This is my code:

```
<a href="<?=base_url('uploads/syarat/'.$username.'/'.$namafile)?>" target="_blank">Show My Pdf</a>
```

I try this and have the same problem:

```
<embed src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/syarat/<?php echo $username.'/'.$namafile;?>" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="
```

When I access directly, the server does not respond.

Comment: Exactly what happens? Have you double checked that the file exists on your hosting server?

Comment: File exist, i try to put it on another folder n i still cant access it

Comment: You still need to let us know what "cant access it" actually means. File not found? Not allowed? Something else? Different issues have different reasons and solutions.

Comment: File exist,  i set to 777, but still can't access it, i dont know, when i access direcly in new tab is going to tab loading never end

Answer (score 0):

actually i can access easyly with google viewer

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
    <a href="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=<?php echo base_url();?>/uploads/syarat/<?php echo $username.'/'.$namafile;?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" role="button"><i class="ace-icon  glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Buka Di Tab Baru</a>
</div><br/>
<object id="pdf" data="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/syarat/<?php echo $username.'/'.$namafile;?>" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```